# Server Report rendering in VB with wrong font size?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am using a server report, which 
I am rendering in VB.net using reportviewer.serverreport.render into a PDF document.

Strangely, when i do this the text in my graphs is really small compared to in the designer or when I view the report in a web browser.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: I don't have detailed info for much of an answer, but I bet the problem is related to the resolution /dpi of the reports that are rendered out. I think .pdf images are generated at 300 dpi by default, but the web images at 96 dpi device settings. If you are specifying anything other than that for target dpi, then it sounds like the chart rendering isn't handling it correctly... (This is built-in chart functionality, correct?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort this out.

For anyone else with this problem, all I did to fix it was set the DeviceInfo string to Nothing ("").

I needed it set as I was also rendering to emf (TIFF) as well, so now I am just setting the DeviceInfo between the two renders.